# How to open a new tab and close all other tabs except the new tab in chrome automatically every single Minute?

Tags: javascript, automation

How can i get a new tab opened and all the other tabs closed except the New Tab automatically in Chrome after a fix interval of time?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Luckily you cannot. How annoying would that be